# XSLT - Replace a value in a variable and keep the result as Node Tree

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I know that this question has surely been asked many time but it's a very specific answer that I would like today.

In my XSL, I've a variable that we will name "A" which contains a node tree and I would like to modify some specific value in this node tree.

```
<xsl:variable name="A">
  <node1>ABC</node1>
  <node2>DEF</node2>
  <node3>
    <node31>ABC</node31>
    <node32>DEF</node32>
  </node3>
</xsl:variable>
```

My goal for this exemple is to replace each value equals to "ABC" in this node tree wherever it is by "123", and store the result in another variable (As we can't update the value of a variable in XSLT).

Meaning that the result that I want is equal to :

```
<xsl:variable name="B">
  <node1>123</node1>
  <node2>DEF</node2>
  <node3>
    <node31>123</node31>
    <node32>DEF</node32>
  </node3>
</xsl:variable>
```

Moreover, the variable "B" MUST be considered a node tree too. It mean that I want the possibility to do B/node1 B/node2 etc...

I found cases but it was considering all the document at one time, but in my case I've filtered a result in a variable and would like to treat it apart.

Sorry that I can't provide the real cases but it's sensible data so I can't afford that.

XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 is allowed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any transformation should be implemented with templates, use a separate mode to ensure that processing doesn't interfere with the rest of the code:

```
  <xsl:mode name="replace-value" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:param name="replacements" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
    select="map { 'ABC' : '123' }"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()[. = map:keys($replacements)]" mode="replace-value">
      <xsl:value-of select="$replacements(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="A">
      <node1>ABC</node1>
      <node2>DEF</node2>
      <node3>
        <node31>ABC</node31>
        <node32>DEF</node32>
      </node3>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="B">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$A" mode="replace-value"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHu

If you want to use a parameter you can change on any `apply-templates` then use a tunnel parameter and move the check into the template of the node(s) you want to transform:

```
  <xsl:mode name="replace-value" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:param name="replacements" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
    select="map { 'ABC' : '123' }"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="replace-value">
      <xsl:param name="replacements" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:value-of
         select="if (map:contains($replacements, .))
                 then $replacements(.)
                 else ."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="A">
      <node1>ABC</node1>
      <node2>DEF</node2>
      <node3>
        <node31>ABC</node31>
        <node32>DEF</node32>
      </node3>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="B">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$A" mode="replace-value">
          <xsl:with-param name="replacements" tunnel="yes" select="$replacements"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="C">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$A" mode="replace-value">
          <xsl:with-param name="replacements" tunnel="yes" select="map { 'DEF' : 'xxx', 'ABC' : 'yyy' }"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:variable>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHu/1

Comment: Sorry I forget about one thing, it's that the filter for the match can change. In your case $replacements is define as a global parameter

Comment: @Farolink, see whether the second suggestion helps for your new requirement. It might be better to ask a new question.

Comment: My savior. Thank you a lot. It's working. Just for my personnal knowledge I'm kind of understanding what the mode do but the tunnel functionnality even on looking on internet I'm not getting it, what is it doing ? 

Thank you !

Comment: @Farolink, with XSLT 1, if you wanted to pass on parameters from e.g. the root node down to leaf nodes you had to ensure that you passed them on explicitly at each level/each use of `xsl:apply-templates`. In XSLT 2 and 3, using tunnel parameters, you can pass them on at a certain level and receive them further down, the processor will take care of passing them on where you don't explicitly pass them on. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#tunnel-params or the section about them in your favourite XSLT 2/3 text book.

Comment: I Still have an issue finally, the return type is considered as a String and not as a node tree. For exemple when I try to do <xsl:value-of select="$B/Name"/> it return nothing.

When I display it with a xsl:message it look good tho'

Comment: $B/node1* sorry

Comment: I get an output at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHu/2 and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHu/3. If you still have problems then it might be better to ask that as a new question where you provide all details in the question in a formatted way, it is hard to exchange details in comments.

Comment: The problem was between the chair and the desktop. Thank you !